# ReactDOM.render() is not working when called again after making the changes in template

Tags: reactjs

The render() function is working fine on the initial call. But when I call it again, via one of the event handler function, it doesn't work. The chrome dev. tools console is not showing any errors at all.

The changes are made on the options array and then I have to display them as list items in the Unordered list.

Sorry for the bad English.

```
let options = ["example"];

let t = 
  <div>
    <h1>indicition app</h1>
    <p>Put your life into the hands of the computer</p>
    <p>Here are your options</p>
    <ul>

    {options.map(text => <li key={text}>{text}</li> )}  //Changes occur here but not showing.

    </ul>
    <form onSubmit={submit}>
      <input type="text" name="input" />
      <button>Add Item</button>
    </form>
  </div>;


function submit(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!e.target.elements.input.value) return;

  options.push(e.target.elements.input.value);
  console.log(options);

  ReactDOM.render(t, document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]); // Here it is not working.
}

ReactDOM.render(t, document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]); //Here it works for once.
```

Answer (score 0):

Render function is automatically called when your state has changed. To do that, create a new class and save your options in the state. After that append your options and save them in the state, using `this.setState`. See the example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MyClass extends Component {
  state = {
    options: ['example'],
  };
  render() {
return (
    <div>
      <h1>indicition app</h1>
      <p>Put your life into the hands of the computer</p>
      <p>Here are your options</p>
      <ul>
        {this.state.options.map((text) => (
          <li key={text}>{text}</li>
        ))}
        //Changes occur here but not showing.
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
        <input type='text' name='input' />
        <button>Add Item</button>
      </form>
    </div>);
  }

  submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!e.target.elements.input.value) return;
    let { options } = this.state;
    options = options.concat(e.target.elements.input.value);
    this.setState({ options });
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(MyClass, document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]); //Here it works for once.
```

Comment: What does the error say? Try defining the class in a new file and use the last line in App.js

Comment: And I want to know what's the problem in my approach. I have seen people use that approach, it works for them but not working when I use it.

Comment: unexpected token (state = ......) . It is pointing to the = operator. And I tried to run it after removing the extra "," in the options object. But still showing the same error.